# cannot update MacBook Air to Monterey from Big Sur

Tags: macos, software-update, big-sur, monterey, auto-update

I have a Macbook Air (11-inch, Early 2014) currently running the latest version of MacOS Big Sur (as of the time of this posting) 11.7.1.

I am regularly getting on-screen notifications that MacOS Monterey is ready to be downloaded and installed, but when I click the notification (or manually navigate to `System Preferences -> Software Update`), the only message I receive is `Your Mac is up to date - MacOS Big Sur 11.7.1`.

This has been going on for months now - since MacOS Monterey was first made available to my machine.  I get a notification that Monterey is available, but then there is no option to actually update and the `Software Update` window doesn't show that Monterey is available.

I have had no problem with Big Sur updates during that time, and I am constantly able to keep my Big Sur version up to date, so there isn't a problem with the update service in that regard.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the question? Is it how to upgrade to Monterey (not easy on your MBA)? Or is it how to turn off the notifications for Monterey upgrade?

Comment: Basically, I thought that the `Software Update` service was somehow malfunctioning and not showing me all the available updates.  Instead, it turns out that the `Software Update` must not be responsible for the notification, seeing as how that panel *does* show me the correct updates available for my model (i.e. *not* Monterey).  Instead, Apple seems to be notifying users of the availability of Monterey without any regard to the compatibility of the device being notified.  This seems an unexpectedly poor choice by Apple, but *c'est la vie*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big Sur is the maximum OS your MacBook Air can (is meant to) run:
[EveryMac.com](https://everymac.com/systems/by_capability/maximum-macos-supported.html)

Ignore the notifications for Monterey.

Comment: Such an obvious answer that I didn't even think to consider. Based on my experiences with other Apple products ("it just works!"), I was assuming I wouldn't be getting the notification if the update wasn't available for my product. Furthermore, since clicking the notification brings me to the `Software Update` panel, I was assuming that the notification *was coming from* the `Software Update` service. If the `Software Update` service is notifying me that an update is available, then certainly it must be available for my Macbook. Guess I was completely wrong. Still, seems like poor design.